# Cross-platform NODE_ENV for Browserify building React app

Tags: node.js, windows, unix, browserify

I have this task in my `package.json`:

```
"watch-js": "set NODE_ENV=production && watchify assets/js/main.js -t babelify -t bulkify -o dist/js/app.js -v --full-path=false",
```

For Windows compatibility, but doesn't work on Unix. My previous command:

```
"watch-js": "NODE_ENV=production watchify assets/js/main.js -t babelify -t bulkify -o dist/js/app.js -v --full-path=false",
```

Didn't work on Windows...what is my best option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross platform NPM start script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971416/cross-platform-npm-start-script)

Comment: check this question's solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971416/cross-platform-npm-start-script

Comment: Or use a package which takes care of this for you, such as this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env