# Cross platform NPM start script

Tags: npm, electron

I'm building out an Electron app that will be developed by folks on both Windows and OS X. I'd like to create a cross-platform start script. So far, I've had exactly zero luck getting something that works. The issue, I think, is that I need to set the `NODE_ENV` environment variable and the syntax is slightly different.

I'm hoping there's a way that I just haven't found yet. My current scripts section follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "start:osx": "NODE_ENV=development electron ./app/",
    "start:win": "set NODE_ENV=development && electron ./app/"
}
```

I'd really like to create a single "start" script and eliminate the platform-specific variants. Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Environment variables are a problem in Windows.

As stated Domenic Denicola (one of the main contributors to npm) :

> This is not npm's job. You can run custom Node scripts to set environment variables using process.env if you'd like, or use something that isn't environment variables (like JSON).
>
> ...
>
> You can write custom scripts to work around connect's limitations, e.g. in your tests modify process.env.
>
> (Reference : [this issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2800))

So we'll manage through a JS script (Solution inspired on this [commit](https://github.com/benoror/angular-formly/commit/139951fdae069966bfd092ba0842c207643a25a1)) :

1. Create a `exec.js` file in a `scripts` directory
2. Copy the following code in `exec.js` :

```js
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var command_line = 'electron ./app/';
var environ = (!process.argv[2].indexOf('development')) ? 'development' : 'production';

if(process.platform === 'win32') {
  // tricks : https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/184#issuecomment-87378478 (Just don't add the space after the NODE_ENV variable, just straight to &&:)      
  command_line = 'set NODE_ENV=' + environ + '&& ' + command_line;
} else {
  command_line = 'NODE_ENV=' + environ + ' ' + command_line;
}

var command = exec(command_line);

command.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  process.stdout.write(data);
});
command.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
  process.stderr.write(data);
});
command.on('error', function(err) {
  process.stderr.write(err);
});
```

3. Update your `package.json` :

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/exec.js development",
}
```

4. Run npm script : `npm run start`

**Edit 05.04.2016**

There is a very useful npm package that allows manages this problem : [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env). Run commands that set environment variables across platforms

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I won't have a chance to test it for a day or so, but upvoting in the interim because it looks like a great solution to the problem. Will mark it as the answer once I know all went well. Thanks again!