# how to create cross platform scripts (multiple command for single line) in package.json (nodeJs)

Tags: node.js, package.json

issue:
in script: 
we want to check env. variable {dev/test/mock} and do following script run based on it.

**if** $mock is true the run **script** start-mock **else** go on reach real test server

---

**scenario 1:**
we added commands aggregated in package.json script section

```
e.g. : "test": "export NODE_ENV=dev; grunt", [on linux]
which is "test": "(SET NODE_ENV=dev) & (grunt)", [on win32]
```

**scenario 2:**
could be bat/sh script sitting in package and we called them out from package.json

**scenario 3:** (permanent solution)
not sure if its already available out there

something like

```
get arguments from script section: to give flexibility and freedom to end user.
 e.g. : "test": "solution.env NODE_ENV=dev; solution grunt"
```

where we can have script to process  (input with process.platform) out put depends on OS.

---

"start-pm2": "if \"%MOCK%\" == \"true\" ( npm run mock & pm2 start process.json --env test ) else ( pm2 start process.json )", [windows] for linux  if.. fi
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross platform NPM start script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971416/cross-platform-npm-start-script)

Comment: Can we run commands on all platform! Thx for env variable but  any idea to have cross-platform command implementation

Answer (score 14):

Use: [run-script-os](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-script-os)

For example:

```
// from pacakge.json
"scripts": {
    // ...
    "dist": "run-script-os",
    "dist:win32": "tar -C dist -cvzf %npm_package_name%-%npm_package_version%.tgz .",
    "dist:linux": "tar -C dist -cvzf $npm_package_name-$npm_package_version.tgz ."
},
```

Answer (score 13):

Lets consider implementation of 3-th solution like e.g.

#### package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "command" : "node bin/command.js"
}
```

#### bin/command.js

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn
const platform = require("os").platform()
const cmd = /^win/.test(platform)
  ? `${process.cwd()}\\bin\\command.bat`
  : `${process.cwd()}/bin/command.sh`

spawn(cmd, [], { stdio: "inherit" }).on("exit", code => process.exit(code))
```

depends on environments script will execute `command.bat` or `command.sh`

Comment: Hello, when running this I get:
Error: spawn bin\removeReports.bat ENOENT. Can you help with this?

Comment: @mismas I've updated and tested above code on Windows, seems to working

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but when I run it this time on Linux (Mac OS to be precise) I'm getting an error: Error: spawn EACCES in the last line of code. On Windows it runs perfectly. Do you have any ideas how to solve it? :D

Comment: Here is a snippet from logs: 
Error: spawn EACESS
at _errnoRxception (util.js:1022:11)
at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:502:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mismas/dev/project/test/config/bin/removeReports.js:7:1)
...

Comment: @mismas pleas try to add x (as executable) flag to that file by running `chmod +x bin/__name_of_executable_file__.sh`

Comment: @mismas seems that exec https://tutorialedge.net/javascript/nodejs/executing-shell-scripts-with-nodejs/ - works without **chmod** settings

Comment: Krzysztof thanks.It worked once I changed flag of .sh file to executable. Is there a way to incorporate that as well in command.js script so it is done "automatically" so that user doesn't have to do it manually? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like this:

`const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
const platform = require("os").platform();

const isWindows = /^win/.test(platform);

if(!isWindows) {
    spawn('chmod', ['+x', '/test/config/bin/removeReports.sh']);
}

const cmd = isWindows
    ? `${process.cwd()}\\test\\config\\bin\\removeReports.bat`
    : `${process.cwd()}/test/config/bin/removeReports.sh`;

spawn(cmd, [], { stdio: "inherit" }).on("exit", code => process.exit(code));`

Comment: @mismas that https://tutorialedge.net/javascript/nodejs/executing-shell-scripts-with-nodejs/ method doesn't require chmod change

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help it worked like a charm with exec. And it is much cleaner. Here is the code: `const exec = require("child_process").exec;
const platform = require("os").platform();

const isWindows = /^win/.test(platform);

const cmd = isWindows
    ? `${process.cwd()}\\test\\config\\bin\\removeReports.bat`
    : `${process.cwd()}/test/config/bin/removeReports.sh`;

exec(cmd);`

Answer (score 8):

You will need to implement solution 3.

You can use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) package that does it for you.

Comment: Thanks @BrunoLM  Can you suggest anything for  [ if..else] cross platform solution

Comment: Maybe you can use [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp) and create custom tasks...

Comment: cross-env is not maintained anymore

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make cross-platform scripts, the best way (for me) is to use Javascript (or any others cross-platform languages) instead of shell/batch. You can take a look at this nodejs framework: [ScriptEase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scriptease-cli). It's a new tool (in BETA) that permit you to easily create scripts in javascript.