# how to run npm based on os

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

i have those 2 npm(s) for each operating system:

```
"pack": "cd dist/fold1 && type script11.js script22.js script33.js > all.js",
"pack-unix": "cd dist/fold1 && cat script11.js script22.js script33.js > all.js"
```

how can i make them a single command?

like:
`"pack": "cd dist/fold1 && <if win than type else cat> script11.js script22.js script33.js > all.js",`

Answer (score 10):

There is a great package for this case called `run-script-os` [link here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-script-os)

Note! You can combine OS tags that have similar scripts.

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "pack": "run-script-os",
    "pack:win32": "...",
    "pack:macos": "...",
    "pack:default": "..."
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`shelljs/shx`](https://github.com/shelljs/shx) as a development only dependency.

```sh
npm install shx --save-dev
```

Then in `package.json`:

```json
pack: "cd dist/fold1 && shx cat script11.js script22.js script33.js > all.js"
```

Using `shx` over `run-script-os` has an advantage that you don't need to write different scripts for different environments. Prefer using [`shelljs`](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) instead if you are having some complex stuff going on. If your use case(s) are not met by both of them (like a dependency on some specific feature that is not supported by ShellJS), then you can use `run-script-os` as the other answer suggests, or you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41551958, if you don't want another dependency.

`shx` doesn't support running arbitrary commands, and setting environment variables. There is another popular alternative for it: [`cross-env`](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env).

Answer (score 4):

[cross-os](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-os) Good npm package for npm scripts

It supports the following os versions.
'aix'
'darwin'
'freebsd'
'linux'
'openbsd'
'sunos'
'win32'

```
"scripts": {
  "foo": "cross-os pack",
  "bar": {
    "darwin": "cd dist/fold1 && type script11.js script22.js script33.js > all.js",
    "linux": "cd dist/fold1 && cat script11.js script22.js script33.js > all.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an NPM package called `run-script-os` ( [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-script-os) | [GitHub](https://github.com/charlesguse/run-script-os) ) that doesn't require you to write any additional files.

And **shx:**  Good for writing one-off commands in npm package scripts (e.g.  `"clean": "shx rm -rf out/"`).

```
npm install shx --save-dev
```

**Reference**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/shx#install

Where in ***package.json***: `pack: "cd dist/fold1 && shx cat script11.js script22.js script33.js > all.js"`

- **ShellJS:**  Good for writing long scripts, all in JS, running via NodeJS (e.g.  `node myScript.js`).
- `shx`  is a wrapper around  [ShellJS](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs)  Unix commands, providing an easy solution for simple Unix-like, cross-platform commands in npm package scripts.

`shx`  is proudly tested on every node release since  `v6`